# Install ProFTPD Using non-default modules mod_sftp

Tags: linux, sftp, proftpd

[ProFTPD module mod_sftp](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html)

I want to set up a file server with sftp and virtual account,so i use ProFTPD.

system info:red hat enterprise linux 6.8-x86_64

proftpd info:proftpd-1.3.6

OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

error: openssl/rand.h: No such file or directory

what i do:

```
mkdir /usr/local/proftpd
mkdir /etc/proftpd
cd /usr/local/src
wget ftp://ftp.proftpd.org/distrib/source/proftpd-1.3.6.tar.gz
tar -zxvf proftpd-1.3.6.tar.gz 
cd /usr/local/src/proftpd-1.3.6    
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/proftpd --sysconfdir=/etc/proftpd --enable-openssl --with-modules=mod_sftp
make
```

ERROR INFO:

```
--------------
Build Summary
--------------
Building the following static modules:
  mod_ident
  mod_quotatab
  mod_quotatab_file
  mod_sftp
  mod_cap

--------------
[root@slave1 proftpd-1.3.6]# make && make install
echo \#define BUILD_STAMP \"`date +"%a %b %e %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"`\" > include/buildstamp.h
cd lib/ && make lib
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/proftpd-1.3.6/lib'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -DLINUX  -I.. -I../include  -g2 -O2 -Wall -fno-omit-
........
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -DLINUX  -I.. -I../include  -g2 -O2 -Wall -fno-omit-frame-pointer -c table.c
table.c:30:26: error: openssl/rand.h: No such file or directory
table.c: In function ‘tab_get_seed’:
table.c:366: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘RAND_bytes’
make[1]: *** [table.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/proftpd-1.3.6/src'
make: *** [src] Error 2
```

Installation

```
The mod_sftp module is distributed with ProFTPD. For including mod_sftp as a staticly linked module, use:
  $ ./configure --enable-openssl --with-modules=mod_sftp ...
Alternatively, mod_sftp can be built as a DSO module:
  $ ./configure --enable-dso --enable-openssl --with-shared=mod_sftp ...
Then follow the usual steps:
  $ make
  $ make install
Note that if the libsodium library is available, mod_sftp will auto-detect this, which enables other supported algorithms. You can ensure that mod_sftp compiles with the libsodium library like so:
  $ ./configure --enable-openssl --with-modules=mod_sftp ... \
    --with-includes=/path/to/libsodium/include \
    --with-libraries=/path/to/libsodium/lib
```

Comment: Before you run ProFTPD's `configure` script, you need to make sure the OpenSSL development libraries are installed, using _e.g._ `yum install openssl-dev`.  Then you can run your `./configure` command, do a `make clean`, then `make` and `make install`.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful.
Now I have a new problem.I need to install proftpd with mod_sftp:mod_sql:mod_sql_mysql

Comment: mod_sql is capable of using OpenSSL for different ways of encrypting passwords stored in database tables.
http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/SQL.html

Comment: i can't find the mysql.h and libmysqlclient.a files for MySQL

Comment: You might try `yum install mysql-devel mysql-lib`, and then re-run `./configure`, `make clean`, `make`, and `make install`.

Comment: if i use rpm install MySQL,how can i get the directory of  header files of MySQL(mysql.h),i wiil edit my question later

Comment: You are not _required_ to provide the location of those headers (using `--with-includes`); the ProFTPD build system is usually smart enough to find them, assuming a default install.

Comment: Maybe I need to put a new question, rather than edit this one.

Comment: Your answer is very clear and correct,Thanks a lot.It can be successfully compiled now.I forgot to install mysql-devel yet QAQ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ProFTPD `mod_sftp` module requires the OpenSSL library; this build error you encountered:

```
error: openssl/rand.h: No such file or directory
```

indicates that OpenSSL is not installed on your system.

Before you run ProFTPD's `configure` script, you need to make sure the OpenSSL *development* libraries are installed, using *e.g.*:

```
$ yum install openssl-dev
```

Then you can run your build commands for ProFTPD again:

```
$ ./configure ...
$ make clean
$ make
$ make install
```

Later, if you find you want to use the `mod_sql` and `mod_sql_mysql` modules, then you will need to install the MySQL libraries:

```
$ yum install mysql-devel mysql-lib
```

You are not *required* to provide the location of the MySQL headers (using `--with-includes` for the ProFTPD `configure` script); the ProFTPD build system is usually smart enough to find them, assuming a default install.

Putting this altogether, then:

```
$ mkdir /usr/local/proftpd
$ mkdir /etc/proftpd
$ cd /usr/local/src
$ yum install mysql-devel mysql-lib openssl-dev
$ wget ftp://ftp.proftpd.org/distrib/source/proftpd-1.3.6.tar.gz
$ tar -zxvf proftpd-1.3.6.tar.gz 
$ cd /usr/local/src/proftpd-1.3.6    
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/proftpd --sysconfdir=/etc/proftpd --enable-openssl --with-modules=mod_sftp:mod_sql:mod_sql_mysql
$ make
$ make install
```

Hope this helps!